# Is there an open-jdk-8 version and if so, how can one obtain it?

Tags: java, java-8

Browsing through the https://openjdk.java.net it's easy to find [open-jdk-11](https://jdk.java.net/11/) but when you go to equivalent [page](https://jdk.java.net/8/) to download the version 8, the site prompts you to go to Oracle to get a version 8 JDK.

> The JDK 8 Early Access Program has concluded. Current versions of JDK
>   8 can be found on www.oracle.com/javadownload

Does the open-jdk start at version 9? As this [page](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) suggests?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. On Ubuntu you can still find it in the repository. `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net) you can download prebuilt binaries for the current version (OpenJDK 12) and previous LTS versions including OpenJDK 8.

Comment: I would add the [RedHat link](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download/) to this (you need to create a free RedHat account)

Comment: There are probably some download resources for OpenJDK but AdoptOpenJDK provides the most complete collection of prebuilt binaries including Linux, Mac, Windows, Solaris, ... Both 64 and 32bit.

Comment: Checksum doesn't match for downloads from AdoptOpenJDK, so I'd prefer the RedHat link.

Comment: @ChristosK. which version did you try to download?